# The Click-Event on wenzhixin multipleSelect-JQuery plugin is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, asp.net-ajax, onclicklistener, multiple-select

**As-Is Situation:**

I am using the wenzhixin JQuery Multiple-Select-Plugin to provide a multiselect dropdownbox (see http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/home/ ). I have two instances of that Multiselect-Dropdownbox on my page (i made it similar in the JSFiddle - but there it seems to work...).

**Problem:**

I can not get the onClick-Listener in my .done()-Method of the two AJAX-Calls to work. In my example below the click()-Event

```
$('#cbTailoringCategory').multipleSelect( { onClick: function() {...} })
```

is not working but it turns the select-field to a multiselect-dropdown. 
But it works when i write the change()-Listener like this (but this fires twice):

```
$('#cbRoles').change(function (event) {
    refreshDiagramNodes();
}).multipleSelect({

});
```

**Question**

How can i get the click()-Event to workd that i do not have to use the change()-Method?

**JsFiddle**

I tried to isolate the problem in JsFiddle but here it is working :-/

https://jsfiddle.net/schludi/6z0ns475/

**Comprehensive in my code with the AJAX-Calls in when...done...jquery:**

The original AJAX-Calls of my code  are the following:

```
var myTailoringCategories = {};
var myKeypointResponsibles = {};
function loadTailoringCategories() {

$.when(
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Services/DiagramService.asmx/GetTailoringCategories',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var pcpTailoringCategories = msg.d;

            $.each(pcpTailoringCategories, function (index, pcpTailoringCategory) {

                myTailoringCategories[pcpTailoringCategory.tailoringcategory] = pcpTailoringCategory.tailoringelements;

                $('#cbTailoringGroups').append($('<option>', {
                    value: pcpTailoringCategory.tailoringelements,
                    text: pcpTailoringCategory.tailoringcategory
                }));
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log('FEHLER! ' + e.responseText);
        }
    }),
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Services/DiagramService.asmx/GetKeypointResponsibles',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var keypointResponsibles = msg.d;

            $.each(keypointResponsibles, function (index, keypointResponsible) {

                myKeypointResponsibles[keypointResponsible] = keypointResponsible;

                $('#cbRoles').append($('<option>', {
                    value: keypointResponsible,
                    text: keypointResponsible
                }));
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log('FEHLER! ' + e.responseText);
        }
    })
).done(function (result1, result2) {
    updateCBFilter();

    // Hier wird aus der Multiselect-Box eine Rollen-Liste
    $('#cbRoles').change(function (event) {
        refreshDiagramNodes();
    }).multipleSelect({

    });

    // Hier wird aus der Multiselect-Box eine Tailoring-Liste
    $('#cbTailoringGroups').multipleSelect({
        onClick: function () {
            alert('Click Event');
        }
    });

    $('#cbTailoringGroups').multipleSelect('refresh');

    //initializeTailoringCategories();
    loadAllDiagramNodes(diagramType);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the function

```
 refreshDiagramNodes();
```

Produced an error so that the Javascript engine exits/terminates earlier - in order of this the script onClick()-Event hasn't fired.